# Parsing this type of data in a CSV/txt format

Tags: python, csv

I have a data that is stored in a csv/txt file.

The format is something that I have not worked with before so I was looking for some direction on how I would go about this.

Since the csv file is large about 70MB I am looking for something that will be efficient.

The data set looks something like this:

```
FMT, 128, 89, FMT, BBnNZ, Type,Length,Name,Format,Columns
FMT, 130, 46, GPS, QBIHBcLLefffB, TimeUS,Status,GMS,GWk,NSats,HDop,Lat,Lng,Alt,Spd,GCrs,VZ,U
FMT, 131, 46, GPS2, QBIHBcLLefffB, TimeUS,Status,GMS,GWk,NSats,HDop,Lat,Lng,Alt,Spd,GCrs,VZ,U
FMT, 196, 24, GPA, QCCCCBI, TimeUS,VDop,HAcc,VAcc,SAcc,VV,SMS
FMT, 197, 24, GPA2, QCCCCBI, TimeUS,VDop,HAcc,VAcc,SAcc,VV,SMS
FMT, 132, 49, IMU, QffffffIIfBB, TimeUS,GyrX,GyrY,GyrZ,AccX,AccY,AccZ,ErrG,ErrA,Temp,GyHlt,AcHlt

GPS, 288111438, 4, 408321800, 1919, 12, 0.81, 34.6724954, -118.3331596, 851.46, 0.07211103, 213.6901, 0.09, 1
GPA, 288111438, 1.01, 0.86, 1.51, 0.28, 1, 288111
SONR, 288111891, 0, 0, 0, 0
RFND, 288111901, 0.00, 0.00
IMU, 288132434, 0.01139331, 0.01001555, 0.0738163, 0.3783027, -1.865716, -9.70467, 0, 0, 49.00554, 1, 1
IMU2, 288132434, 0.01213987, 0.01530177, 0.06975921, 0.3055397, -1.755074, -9.364305, 0, 0, 52, 1, 1
SONR, 288132959, 0, 0, 0, 0
RFND, 288132969, 0.00, 0.00
ATT, 288133031, 0.00, 9.62, 0.00, -0.53, 0.00, 30.64, 0.02, 0.01
```

As you can see first it gives me how the data is structured. 
After that, depending on the frequency of data being captured, it lists that that parameter and it is corresponding values.

There are about 800 Parameters that get captured I won't be using all of them. I will just be plotting some of those to usually `TimeUS`.

So I am wondering if I should just create a list for each variable I will use. For example for IMU there would a list of 6 columns that carry `TimeUS, Guyrx, GuyrY..etc`.

Or if there is a python module that could help me with this?

Edit: Here is what I have so far:

```
import csv
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

desiredData = 'IMU'
data = []
with open('data2.csv', 'r') as csvfile:
    content = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',')
    for row in content:
        if desiredData == row[0]:
            data.append(row[1])
fig1 = plt.figure(figsize= (10,10))
ax = fig1.add_subplot(111)
mSec = data[:3]
Alt = data[:4]
ax.plot(mSec, Alt, label='Alt(m)', color = 'r')
plt.legend(loc='best',prop={'size':10})
plt.grid(True)
ax.set_xlabel('Time (s)')
ax.set_ylabel('Alt (m)')
```

However, I am getting this error: ValueError: x and y must have same first dimension. Also it is taking a bit of time running this code. Is this normal?

Comment: Do you know regex? https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html

Comment: @kame So with this method I will manually find each header and pull data that is in the row? or actually do they call those headers if the header is not in the row and it is in the column?

Answer (score 0):

Here's some of the things I can think of to parse the csv file efficiently

A simple string split should help you get the fields you need, and parse them based on the value of the fields that indicate the record format.

Process as much of the computations as you can, so you don't have to keep a lot of values and keep your memory footprint low.

Use mmap if possible which is faster for sequential reads.

Dump stuff into the disk(database?) as proactively as possible, to again reduce your memory footprint.

Comment: I edited what I have done so far on the main page. Is this what you meant?